# indentifier was not being initialized

Tags: c++, syntax-error

was doing school project here and run into a problem
My program was support to be user guessing a number which is 47 and if they got it wrong they have 5 total of 5 tries. if still didnt get it the program will exit. If they got it there will be a message saying that how many tries it took for then to get the answer.
Therefore, i have to have a identifier for the number of tries it took. But C++ says that i didnt initialized the identifier. Please help

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int intSecretNum = 47;
  int intGuess;
  int GuessNum;
  cout<< "Guess the secret number (between 0 and 100 inclusively): ";
  cin>> intGuess;
while(intSecretNum != 47, GuessNum<= 5)
{
        if( intGuess < intSecretNum)
            cout << "Your Number is smaller than the secret number";
        else if (intGuess > intSecretNum)
            cout << "Your Number is bigger than the secret number";
        GuessNum++;
        if(GuessNum>5)
            cout << "Sorry, you have used up all your quota (5 times)! The secret number is "<<intSecretNum;
            cout << "program terminated." <<endl;
}
cout<< "You have used "<<GuessNum <<" to guess te secret number which is " <<intSecretNum<<".";
cout<<"program terminated."<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Please help =D

Comment: The compiler is right. `GuessNum` is not initialized. Also, `while (intSecretNum != 47, GuessNum <= 5)` is incorrect. Use `&&` in place of the comma.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to initialize `GuessNum`:

```
int GuessNum = 0;
             ^^^
```

Additionally, the comma in the `while` condition does not do what you think it does, you mean `&&` which is "and" in C++.

Comment: And `cout << "program terminated." <<endl;` is not within the conditional.

Comment: @BillLynch Gotta leave some of the fun to OP. :)